# Swift Spritekit dissipating Gravity field

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a game in swift using spritekit. If you tap the screen it will create a radial gravity field and pull all the other objects in. I create the gravity field like so

```
var fieldNode = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField();

fieldNode.falloff = 0.5;
fieldNode.strength = 1;
fieldNode.animationSpeed = 0.5;
```

It works but my problem is that I only want a sprite to be affected only when it is when it within a certain distance to the centre of the radial gravity, and i will have more than 1 sprite. The way I see it is that there are 2 ways to do it, 1. When a sprite is too far turn off the radial gravity for that sprite or 2. Make the radial gravity dissipate after a certain radius. There is also an overall gravity for the scene.

So the main question is:

How can I either turn off 1 gravity for a sprite OR make a radial gravity dissipate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field node's [`region`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKFieldNode/region) property determines its area of effect. The associated [`SKRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKRegion_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/SKRegion) object lets you define a circular region by its radius.

You can also use the [`fieldBitMask`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/fieldBitMask) on a physics body and the `categoryBitMask` on a field to selectively control which fields affect which bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
    let radius: CGFloat = 1000.0
    gravityField.strength = Float(pow(radius, 2)) * pow(10, -3)
```